# Corrupted file from aws s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The file I get from the backend says it's corrupted (pdf) or shows nothing (image/png).

This is how I upload to AWS:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

try {
  await s3.upload({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: filename,
    Body: file,
    ContentType: mimetype,
    ContentDisposition: contentDisposition,
  }).promise();

    return { success: true, data: null };
  } catch(e) {
    return { success: false, data: null, message: e.code };
}
```

This is how I get the object from AWS

```
try {
  const data = await s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: idAWSFile}).promise()

  return { success: true, data }
} catch(e) {
  return { success: false, data: null, message: e.code };
}
```

This is the object I get in the client side.

```
{
  AcceptRanges: "bytes",
  Body: <Buffer>,
  ContentDisposition: "attachment; filename = "blablabla"",
  ContentLength: 23361,
  ContentType: "application/pdf",
  ETag: <randomnumbers>,
  LastModified: <DATE>,
  Metadata: {},
}
```

This is how I'm trying to download it in the client side:

```
const blob = new Blob([data.Body], { type: data.ContentType });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
window.open(url)
```

What have I tried doing:

1. I tried with `file-saver` and same result -> corrupted file
2. I tried using `toString(utf-8)` on the Body in the `s3.getObject` function as I saw in other SO answers. But when I do this I get gibberish in the Body on the client side and don't know and haven't found what to do with it.

Comment: read Body not data.

Comment: My mistake, this was from another thing I was trying. Fixed it. Still the same corrupted file.

Comment: What happens if you download the file through the console web ui? This will tell you if the issue is in your upload or download code

Comment: @mhbrooks I didn't knew you could do that, but I solved it already. I'll post the answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change in the way I was getting the `blob`, in the client side, solved it.

```
const blob = new Blob([Buffer.from(data.Body, 'binary')], {type: data.ContentType})
```

Comment: Where did you include the blob object though?